# Variable substitution not working to pass --exclude options to tar command

Tags: linux, unix, environment-variables, tar

I am trying to pass some `--exclude` statements to my `tar` command via an env var (in reality I would be passing several `--exclude` statements, and trying to improve readability by putting the definition on a separate line):

```
# EXCLUDE_STUFF="--exclude='/captain/generated'"
# tar ${EXCLUDE_STUFF} -cvzf /dev/null /captain
/captain/
/captain/generated/
/captain/generated/registry-auth
... etc ...
```

i.e. it's not excluding the folder I've specified.  It doesn't make a difference if I surround `${EXCLUDE_STUFF}` in quotes.

This is what I get when I echo the above command:

```
# echo tar ${EXCLUDE_STUFF} -cvzf /dev/null /captain
tar --exclude='/captain/generated' -cvzf /dev/null /captain
```

So it looks like the command is correct.  And when I run the expanded command directly, I get:

```
# tar --exclude='/captain/generated' -cvzf /dev/null /captain
/captain/
/captain/temp/
/captain/data/
... etc ...
```

i.e. the specified folder *has* been excluded.

So why is the variable substitution not working in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is the variable substitution not working in this context?

After assignment the variable `EXCLUDE_STUFF` contains *literally* the string `--exclude='/captain/generated'`.

You are passing `--exclude='/captain/generated'` from the variable substitution. Because there is no directory named *literally* `'` relative to your current working directory, `'/captain/generated'` does not match anything, so it does not exclude anything.

In short `tar --exclude='/captain/generated'` is not the same as `tar "--exclude='/captain/generated'"`.

In this case, just

```
exclude_stuff="--exclude=/captain/generated"
tar "$exclude_stuff" ...
```

Or use bash arrays:

```
exclude_stuff=( --exclude='/captain/generated' )  # note: quotes are interpreted
tar "${exclude_stuff[@]}" ...
```

Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 . Research shell quoting, how it works, and when by it, research word splitting expansion and filename expansion. Check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net . Prefer to use lower case variables for script local variables.

Comment: This is really helpful answer, thanks.  What has me slightly confused is the bit about the presence of a single quote not matching anything, so it does not exclude anything.... but the docs for `tar` suggest wrapping the exclude pattern in single quotes: https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/exclude.html#index-exclude-1 ... and why does it work when you run the command directly (without variable substitution but with single quotes included)?  So are two different commands being run (with variable / without variable)?

Comment: Also, `tar "$exclude_stuff"` doesn't work... but `tar $exclude_stuff` does.

Comment: You stated that `It doesn't make a difference if I surround ${EXCLUDE_STUFF} in quotes`. Add `set -x` to your script and see what is happenning. Research how to debug bash scripts. `tar suggest wrapping the exclude pattern in single quotes` Where? `why does it work when you run the command directly...` Because the variable contains the character `'` in it, wheres directly quotes are interpreted as part of shell parsing.. There is a difference between `echo "stuff"` and `echo "'stuff'"` and `a="'stuff'" ; echo $a`. Please research shell quoting. `are two different...` yes.

Comment: OK thanks... looks like some more research is required... regarding "tar suggest wrapping the exclude pattern in single quotes -- Where?"... the example in the link I included in my first comment has the exclude pattern wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: Yes, `--exclude='*.o'` is wrapped to prevent _shell_ from doing filename expansion. Quotes are removed by shell and then `--exclude=*.o` is passed to tar. Add `set -x` before the command and see what is really executed.

Comment: OK, using `set -x` helps greatly to see exactly what is going on, and it's apparent that the content of `$exclude_stuff` is itself wrapped in single quotes in the resulting command, i.e. it expands to `tar '--exclude=/captain/generated' -cvzf ...` so there is no need for internal wrapping with single quotes in the variable itself... those just end up as literal quotes when expanded, as you mentioned.  And the same if your pattern itself has a wildcard e.g. `$exclude_stuff=/captain/generated/*` doesn't need (and mustn't have) single quotes internally.

Comment: Another subtlety regarding whether to enclose in double quotes i.e. `tar "$exclude_stuff"` vs `tar $exclude_stuff`... in this case it should be the latter (no quotes) to work properly.  Example: `exclude_stuff="--exclude=/captain/generated --exclude=/captain/temp/*"` ... with double quotes the entire expansion is wrapped in single quotes: `tar '--exclude=/captain/generated --exclude=/captain/temp/*' -cvzf ...` whereas without double quotes each part is wrapped in single quotes *if required*: `tar --exclude=/captain/generated '--exclude=/captain/temp/*' -cvzf ...` -- clearly the latter is right

Comment: Use bash arrays. Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 . `--exclude=/captain/temp/*` undergoes filename expansion. You should quote your variables. `clearly the latter is right` You are lucky -  your paths have no spaces so word splitting does nothing, and there are no files that match filename expansion and `shopt -s nullglob` is not set.

Comment: But `'--exclude=/captain/temp/*'` doesn't undergo filename expansion presumably, because the entire thing is wrapped in single quotes... this is what you get when expanding without double quotes, i.e. `tar $exclude_stuff ...`  (but I appreciate that bash arrays is the way to go here)

Comment: `what you get when expanding without double quotes, i.e. tar $exclude_stuff` No, it is not. See: `a="'variable*'" ; touch "'variable_file'" "'variable_another_file'"; echo $a`. Shell variables work more like macros. Qoutes are scanned once, on the input line. Unquoted _result_ of variable expansion undergo word splitting and filename expansion. In the result of unqouted variable expansion, quotes are irrelevant - are literal characters.

Comment: OK thanks very much for the help and guidance.